# Delete text after revision using \st{}

Tags: revision-control

I used `\st{}` with `soul` package. Now, what is the best way to delete the text inside all occurrences of `\st{}`?

Comment: Are you willing to lose the `\st` command? I.e., `\renewcommand\st[1]{}`.

Comment: perfect. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply redefine `\st` to consume its argument

```
\renewcommand\st[1]{}
```

And there are two additional details that could be covered.

Depending on your rigor with striking out spaces, the above definition can leave two consecutive spaces between words (so irregular spacing). The more advanced definition is

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\st[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}
\makeatother
```

That's not a guarantee of fixed spacing though. If you have `test \st{this}.` you will get a space before the period.

The other detail is that this is single-shot revision control. If you are going to go through cycles of revision you may want different strike-through commands, as with

```
\usepackage{soul}
\makeatletter
\let\stC=\textst
\newcommand\stB[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}
\renewcommand\st[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}
\makeatother
```

so that `\stC` will do strike-through for revision C, but `\stB` and `\st` will disappear.  Note that `\textst` is the underlying command name for `\st`.

Comment: Yes, typo on the last line. Fixing.